# Python3 - List comprehension: Not in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have some simple code:

```
list1 = [['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
list2 = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

for l in list2:

    new_list = [x for x in list1 if x[0] != l]
    print(new_list)
```

I want my output to be:

```
'four'
'five'
'six'
```

...instead however I am getting:

```
[['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
[['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog']]
[['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
[['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
[['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
```

...what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain your expected output?

Comment: expected output is as above...two, four, five and six are not in list1, so that is the expected output. not really sure why two downvotes? this is a working piece of code...compact, runable and with a required and actual output given...

Comment: @gdogg371 But `'two'` is in `list1[1]` and not in `list2`... Please explain the actual algorithm you're trying to implement.

Comment: i have removed 'two' from the expected output.

Comment: Please also [edit] the explanation to the question. As it stands, your question is really not clear

Comment: If you had inteded to keep 'two' in the output the following would work but you'd lose the order and have to check against the original lists to maintain it-  for elem in {x[0] for x in list1}.symmetric_difference(set(list2)): print(elem)

Answer (score 4):

Your current solution is only filtering sub lists from `list1` where the first element is not equal to the element from `list2`.

Instead you want to filter elements from `list2` that don't exist at all from the first elements in `list1`, then print them out line by line.

An `O(n)` solution would be to convert `list1` to a set of only first elements, since set lookups are `O(1)`, then print out elements from `list2` that don't exist in this set.

```
list1 = [['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
list2 = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

lookups = {sublst[0] for sublst in list1}
# {'three', 'one', 'two'}

for item in list2:
    if item not in lookups:
        print(item)
```

Or a slower `O(n * m)` solution using [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) to check every sublist in `list1` individually. `n` would be the number of items in `list2`, and `m` would be the number of sub lists in `list1`.

```
for item in list2:
    if all(item != sublst[0] for sublst in list1):
        print(item)
```

Which can also be done with [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any):

```
for item in list2:
    if not any(item == sublst[0] for sublst in list1):
        print(item)
```

**Output:**

```
four
five
six
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list1 = [['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
list2 = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

s = set(f for f, *_ in list1)   # OR s = set(f[0] for f in list1)
out = [v for v in list2 if v not in s]

print(*out, sep='\n')
```

Prints:

```
four
five
six
```

Comment: A bit simpler: `s = {x[0] for x in list1}`

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah, maybe it's too "clever"

Answer (score 2):

You are printing a new list in every iteration. I believe this is what you meant to do?

```
list1 = [['one', 'blue', 'cat'], ['two', 'green', 'dog'], ['three', 'red', 'horse']]
list2 = ['one', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']

list3 = []
for l in list1:
    list3 += l

new_list = [w for w in list2 if w not in list3]
print('\n'.join(new_list))
```

Output:

```
four
five
six
```

Comment: it's an 'l' not a '1' as stated above, however your answer does work.

Comment: @gdogg371 This is exactly why [PEP 8 recommends against using `l` as a variable name](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid).